# How to find the coordinates of a matrix in a new basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a set of matrices $B=\{A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4\}$ that form a basis in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to find the coordinates of a matrix $Y_E$ given in the standard basis in this new basis.

I know that the formula for finding these coordinates is:
$$
\begin{equation}
Y_E = T_{E\rightarrow B}Y_B 
\end{equation}
$$
and so to find $Y_B$ we can do the following:
$$
\begin{equation}
T_{E\rightarrow B}^{-1}Y_E = T_{B\rightarrow E}Y_E = Y_B 
\end{equation}
$$
In $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is easy because the transformation matrix is a normal matrix. But for this case, the transformation matrix is a matrix of matrices, so how can I find $Y_B$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an isomorphism between $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb R^4$ that involves “flattening” the matrix. Use that.

Comment: @amd Thanks! I have found the isomorphism. I have not practiced these topics in a long time. The isomorphism is this: https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/linear-algebra/real-euclidean-vector-spaces/more-vector-spaces-isomorphism